# Can't retrieve metric value from OpenTSDB

Tags: opentsdb

Just to try out OpenTSDB, I'm trying to just add a metric value and retrieve it. I've done the following to add a new metric value, but I can't seem to retrieve it properly. Any advice?

**Request 1: Put new metric value**

URL: `http://localhost:4242/api/put?details`

Method: `POST`

Body:

```
{
    "metric": "test",
    "timestamp": 1495664539104,
    "value": 20,
    "tags": {
        "subject": "subject"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "failed": 0,
    "errors": []
}
```

**Request 2: get metric value back**

URL: `http://localhost:4242/api/query/last`

Method: `POST`

Body:

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "metric": "test",
            "tags": {
                "subject": "subject"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response: `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled meta data table? For that, you should set `tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking` or `tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts` to true (in opentsdb settings).

Or you can try to use back scan (number of hours to scan) parameter for your query like:

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "metric": "test",
            "tags": {
                "subject": "subject"
            }
        }
    ],
    "backScan":24
}
```

See [documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/last.html)